# Elastic search client for Python: advice?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm writing some scripts for our sales people to query an index with elastic search through python. (Eventually the script will update lead info in our Salesforce DB.)

I have been using the urllib2 module, with simplejson, to pull results. The problem is that this seems to be a not-so-good approach, evidenced by scripts which are taking longer and longer to run.

Questions:

1. Does anyone have any opinions (opinions, on the internet???) about Elastic Search clients for Python? Specifically, I've found pyes and pyelasticsearch, via elasticsearch.org---how do these two stack up?
2. How good or bad is my current approach of dynamically building the query and running it via `self.raw_results = simplejson.load(urllib2.urlopen(self.query))`?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "longer and longer".....profile your code and don't guess what could slow...

Comment: Fair enough, but the code is simple enough that I'm fairly certain who the culprit is.

Comment: it would be great if you share more code. the

Comment: The profiler *tells* you...so profile it

Comment: @pranshus: not sure what code to post here. It's mostly putting strings together (binding query params to a url), and the only real non-trivial statement so far is the query execution, which is the line I posted above (it lives in a Query class, which I could post if you think it's helpful). I haven't attempted to implement any kind of threading, either, which is another improvement I could make. Anyway, the code I would post is just a for loop running over the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use pyes. And its pretty neat. You can there go with the thrift protocol which is faster then the rest service.

Comment: 15 months later...circle gets the square! PyES is, indeed, the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an issue unrelated to the client.  If you can pare down what's being sent to ES and represent it in a simple curl command it will make what's actually running slowly more apparent.  I suspect we just need to tweak your query to make sure it's optimal for your context.